# How to get the Thread group name in Jmeter dashboard APDEX view?

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way to present the Thread group name in which the tests are run
somewhere here : 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [__threadGroupName() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) as prefix or postfix for the sampler, this way it will be added to the sampler label everywhere: in .jtl file, reports, charts, etc.

- JMeter Test Plan:

  [image]
- Dashboard:

  [image]

The function is available since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)

Comment: is there any way to automate this function ? 
i mean it is allot of work to go throw every method

Comment: It is, you can add i.e. [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as the direct child of the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and use the following code: `prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel(true))` 

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thanks , is it also only jmeter 5 version API ?
I only 1 per Test plan ? and it will add the info to each thread group and its children ?

Comment: It should work for [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) and higher. The PostProcessor will add the Thread Group label to all Samplers in its [Scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules).